# How to get process memory usage WINAPI

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

I have the problem . I am trying to get process memory usage , but unfortunatly some process always returning the same value in my case - 3276. How can I get the real amount of memory using by the process. Thanks in advance.

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
            PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS memCounter;
            BOOL result = GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess,
                                   &memCounter,
                                   sizeof( memCounter ));

            char procID[20];
            char procMem[100];
            sprintf_s(procMem, "%d",(memCounter.WorkingSetSize/1024/1024));
            if (!(strcmp(procMem,"3276"))) {

            strcpy(procMem, "<unavaliable>");

            }
            sprintf_s(procID, "%d",entry.th32ProcessID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the return values for errors. You simply must do that. Clearly one of them is failing. Is it `OpenProcess`, or is it  `GetProcessMemoryInfo`? How can we tell without any error checking. Read the documentation for the function and follow the instructions there given to check for errors.

Once you identify which function is failing you can try to work out why. In case of failure, both of these functions will set the last error value and so you can call `GetLastError` to discern what went wrong.

Quite possibly `OpenProcess` is failing because you are asking for too many access rights. All you need is `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ`. Another possible failure mode is that some system processes will not give up this information. Ultimately you need to perform error checking to diagnose the specific problem.

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx error code 6 is invalid handle. Which function call gives you that?